# PowerCLI: how to provide a password or credential for a guest OS which has no password set?

Tags: vmware, vsphere, powercli

I want some system info of a guest OS, the script goes like this:

```
  $script = '&"$env:ProgramFiles\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSInfo\msinfo32.exe" /report "$env:Tmp\inforeport"'

  Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText $script -VM $targetVM
```

unfortunately it failed with the error:

```
Invoke-VMScript     SSPI NTLM: InitializeSecurityContext failed for target 'PC\TOM'. Error code: 0x8009030E
```

PC\TOM is my username in my pc.

This clearly is due to a lack of credentials. **But the guest OS doesn't have a password**.  I try to pass the guest OS username only:

```
Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText $script -VM $targetVM -GuestUser administrator
```

It failed undoubtly:`Invoke-VMScript     value cannot be null. Parameter name : s`

So how to provide a password or credential for a guest OS which has no password set, if I don't want to manually log in the guest OS and set a password?

Comment: Have you tried -GuestPassword "" or $pass = "" then -GuestPassword = $pass or -GuestPassword $null

Comment: to user3520245, I tried as you said today, it doesn't work. By the way, I finally had the password set to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I received that message until I submitted "-GuestCredential"

```
$localCreds = Get-Credential
Invoke-VMScript -VM <vmname> -ScriptType Powershell -GuestCredential $localCreds -ScriptText $(Get-content .\theScript.ps1)
```